# Работа с json в python

Tags: python, json

Есть такой код:

```
param = {'user_id': 1, "field": 'bdate', 'v': 5.52}
url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?' + parse.urlencode(param)
resp = request.urlopen(url).read().decode("utf8")

json_data = json.dumps(resp) 
parsed_json = json.loads(json_data)
```

Как правильно достать данные из ответа json? Пробовал так:

```
print(parsed_json[0]['id'])
```

И так:

```
print(parsed_json["response"]['id'])
```

Но ничего не получается.
Python версии 3.5.

Comment: "ничего не получается" - понятие растяжимое. Стектрейс в студию.

Comment: Кажется, вот это вообще лишнее: json_data = json.dumps(resp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по докам vk, ответ должен быть `{"response":[{"id":210700286, ...`,
значит для получения id:

```
id = parsed_json["response"][0]["id"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [vk-requests](https://github.com/prawn-cake/vk-requests), библиотека реализует всё необходимое и очень удобна в использовании.

Пример использования:

```
import vk_requests

api = vk_requests.create_api(app_id=123, login='User', password='Password')
api.users.get(user_ids=1)
[{'first_name': 'Pavel', 'last_name': 'Durov', 'id': 1}]
```

Т.е не нужно заботиться о том как достать данные, это происходит автоматически в понятном для разработчика формате.